# Link from textbox report to another report(not sub report)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have to keep a link in one of the `textbox` from where it has To be redirected to another report(Not Sub report).

The `Parameter` of The report is the value of the `textbox` itself. But when I tried it worked properly when the report is separately executed. But when I link to the Page it doesn't redirect to the report.

Please help me on this, I am wasting my days on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add Drillthrough report links where clicking on one report will take you to another report.

Here are some links, which may be helpful [Link1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159847%28v=sql.90%29.aspx),[Link2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519554.aspx)